# Is there a way to grant access to a contact without giving access to the parent account?

Tags: sharing, standard-objects

We have a request to be able to toggle the visibility of both accounts and contacts on and off based on an active checkbox. To accomplish this I have set OWDs to private, and then created a sharing rule that shares the accounts and contacts with all internal users when they are marked as active. What I am finding though is that if I have an account that is inactive but a contact that is active, the users are also able to access that inactive account. I am under the impression there is no way to prevent this but if anyone knows a way I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Built-in Sharing Behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_across_objects.htm&type=5) states:

> **Access to a parent account**—If you have access to an account’s child record, you have implicit Read Only access to that account.

So you can't prevent access to the account if a user can see the contact. This would have undesirable side effects in reports and list views, so it's not allowed.